# Identifying element using Protractor with Typescript in an Angular 7 app

Tags: typescript, protractor

I tried to identify a particular button by XPath, CSS and by model, but without any success. By model is not accepted in Angualr 7. By XPath the way is not recognized. Tried also with css but I didn't succeed. Can somebody help me with a good css identifier?

[Here is the part from where I need to identify the element:Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTRNA.png)

Here is the part from where I need to identify the element:

```
<div _ngcontent-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <a _ngcontent-c15="" mat-icon-button="" mattooltip="Open Data Mart (DE)" class="mat-icon-button"
        aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-15" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-message="Open Data Mart (DE)"
        ng-reflect-query-params="[object Object]" ng-reflect-router-link="/active,reports" tabindex="0"
        aria-disabled="false"
        href="/de/active/reports?id=5e7795ab-6f88-47e4-9e53-c3e52ffbf078&amp;sourceId=92ef315f6b194907f8aa08d6965368d8"
        style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
            <img _ngcontent-c15="" height="24" src="assets/open-datamart-blue.svg" width="24">
        </span>
        <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="true"
            ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="https://taxmart-web-dev-v2.tax">
        </div>
        <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
    </a>
    <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }-->
</div>
```

Some of the versions that I try but without success:

```
const activeDataClick = element(by.cssContainingText('ng-reflect-router-link="/active,reports"','/active,reports'));
const activeDataClick = element(by.css('.active,reports'));
const activeDataClick = element(by.css('[ng-reflect-router-link="/active,reports]'));
const activeDataClick = element(by.css('.Open Data Mart (DE)'));
const activeDataClick = element(by.css('a[href*="/active,reports"]'));
const activeDataClick = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-main/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/app-active-datamarts-tabs/div/mat-card/app-active-datamarts/mat-table/mat-row/mat-cell[6]/div/a/div[2]'));
```

Comment: What error/output do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend a lot on what are the most predictable element around the img you are trying to locate.

The most straight forward to try would be just finding the image based on the src.

```
element(by.xpath('//img[@src="assets/open-datamart-blue.svg"]') //xpath
element(by.css('[src="assets/open-datamart-blue.svg"]') //css
```

If that is not unique you could find it as a child of that `span`,`a` or `div`. The below example uses div

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@class="ng-star-inserted"]//img[@src="assets/open-datamart-blue.svg"]') //xpath
element(by.css('.ng-star-inserted [src="assets/open-datamart-blue.svg"]') //css
```

---

Most of the syntaxs you have attempted are incorrect so I would advise looking up how css and xpath locators are meant to be used. I corrected some below

```
cssContainingText('[ng-reflect-router-link="/active,reports"]','/active,reports')
css('[ng-reflect-router-link="/active,reports"]')
css('[mattooltip="Open Data Mart (DE)"]')
```